# Concerning the answer to why $Sp(2n)$ is a Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133377/205193

I understand the proof, but I don't understand what $f$ is,

could it be the application $A\mapsto A^TJA-J $, where $J$ is a canonical skew-symmetric matrix?

Furthermore, how do you find the differential of such function, since it involves matrices?

Comment: It is the map you suspect. Real matrices form a finite dimensional vector space, so you are dealing with a function from $\mathbb R^{n^2}$ (or the open subset of invertible matrices) to $\mathbb R^m$. Thus the standard setting for calculus applies.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to explain a proof that works for every subgroup of $GL(n)$ such that preserves a non-degenerate bilinear form.

Let $B$ a non-degenerate bilinear form on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Claim 1:There is a linear map $*:L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$, such that  for all $\phi \in L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ holds that $B(\phi u,v)=B(u,\phi^{*}v)$ and $(\phi\psi)^*=\phi^*\psi^*$.

Claim 2 : $*:L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a involution, i.e., $(\phi^*)^*=\phi$.

Denote by $L^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ the space of the $\phi$'s such that $\phi^*=\phi$, and $L^{a}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ the space of the $\phi$'s such that $\phi^*=-\phi$. We can use the claim 2 or the fact that any $\phi= \frac{\phi+\phi^*}{2}+\frac{\phi-\phi^*}{2}$ to show that $$L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)=L^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)\oplus L^{a}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n).$$

Claim 2: The subset $G_B$ of $GL(n)$ that preserves $B$ is a subgroup, i.e., the subset of $\phi \in GL(n)$ such that $B(\phi u, \phi v)=B(u,v)$ for all $u,v\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Claim 3: $G_B=\{\phi\in GL(n): \phi\phi^{*}=Id\}$

Claim 4: The map $\mathcal{A}: L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n) \rightarrow L^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$, $\mathcal{A}(\phi)=\phi\phi^{*}$ is a smooth map.

Proof: The matrix product is a bilinear function $\cdot:L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n) \times L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$. The map $i(\phi)=(\phi,\phi^{*})$ is a linear map from $i:L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)\times L(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$. The map is smooth because is the composition of this two maps.

Claim 5:The differential of $\mathcal{A}$ is the map $D\mathcal{A}:L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)\rightarrow L^{s}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)$ given by $D\mathcal{A}|_{\phi}(V)=V\phi^* + \phi V^*$.

Proof: From the claim 4 we know that $\mathcal{A}$ is the composition of a bilinear map and a linear map, we can use the chain rule to calculate its differential. The differential of the multiplication is $D(\cdot)|_{(\phi,\psi)}(U,V)=U\psi+\phi V$ and $Di|_{\phi}(V)=(V,V^{*})$, so we conclude that 
$D\mathcal{A}|_{\phi}=D(\cdot)|_{(\phi,\phi^*)}\circ Di|_{\phi}(V)=V\phi^*+\phi V^{*}$.

Claim 6: If $\phi\phi^* = Id$ then $D\mathcal{A}|_{\phi}$ is surjective, i.e., $Id$ is a regular value of $\mathcal{A}$.

Proof: Let $W\in L^s(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$, take $V=\frac{1}{2}\phi W$ then 
$$D\mathcal{A}|_{\phi}(V)=\frac{1}{2}\phi(W\phi)^{*}+\frac{1}{2}W\phi\phi^{*}=\frac{1}{2}(W^{*}+W)=W.$$

Claim 7: $G_B$ is an embedded submanifold of $GL(n)$.

Claim 8: $G_B$ is a Lie group.

In the specific case of symplectic form, $B(u,v)=u^{T}Jv$, then we can deduce that $\phi^{*}=-J\phi^TJ$, consequently $\mathcal{A}(\phi)=-\phi J\phi^{T}J$. We can see that $-\phi J\phi^{T}J=Id$ if, only if $\phi J\phi^T=J$ or equivanlentely $\phi J\phi^{T} - J=0$.

I believe that the claims are not so hard to prove, I can explain more If there is some doubt.