# Under what conditions is the matrix exponential $ e^A $ symplectic?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

Let $ A \in \Bbb R^{2n \times 2n}$ and let the matrix exponential $ e^A $ be defined by

$$ e^A := \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^k}{k!}.$$

I want to ask under what conditions the matrix $ e^A $ is symplectic, i.e.,

$$ (e^A)^TJe^A=J,$$

where
$$
J=\left(\begin{matrix}
0 & I_n\\
-I_n& 0
\end{matrix}\right).
$$

I have known that if $ B $ is symmetric, then
$$
(e^{JB})^TJe^{JB}=J.
$$
However, it seems that I cannot apply this to the original problem. Can you give me some hints or referneces?

Comment: If $A^TJ+JA = 0$ the exponential is symplectic. See the answer for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445088/finding-the-lie-algebra-of-the-symplectic-lie-group